# C# delete a single row in an SQL bound datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have attempted many solutions that state only one row is deleted but in my VS2017 C# from the selected row to the end of the DataGridView all rows are deleted. If I have 5 rows and I delete the 4th row, both the 4th and 5th rows are deleted. I can add rows with no problems and I can drop the table and create the table but deleting a single row of data seems not doable.

Please help, I've been at this for a few days...

```
private void DDataTable_UserDeletedRow( object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e )
{
  try
  {
    // Want the last operation to be completed
    dbDataSetBindingSource.EndEdit();
    //dbTableAdapter.Update( dbDataSet );

    if ( selectedCellRow > 0 )
    {
      DataRowView drv = ( DataRowView )dbDataSetBindingSource.Current;
      DataRow drToDelete = drv.Row;
      dbDataSet.MyTable.Rows.Remove( drToDelete );
    // This removed all remaining rows
    //  DDataTable.Rows.Remove( this.DDataTable.SelectedRows[ 0 ] );
    // This removed all remaining rows 
    //  dbDataSetBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    // This gave an error "Can't remove items not in the list?
    //  dbDataSetBindingSource.Remove( selectedRowStr );

      dbDataSetBindingSource.EndEdit();
      dTableAdapter.Update(dbDataSet);
    }
    else
      MessageBox.Show( "Error in delete row, bad index." );
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  //  CancelEventArgs myE = new CancelEventArgs();
  //  DDataTable_Validating( sender, myE );
    string myStr = "Error in deleting row\n" + ex.Message;
    MessageBox.Show( myStr, "User Delete a Row" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `drToDelete.Delete()`, then update dataset by calling `dbDataSet.MyTable.AcceptChanges();`

Or you can just call:

```
dbDataSet.MyTable.Rows.RemoveAt(dbDataSetBindingSource.Position);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the drToDelete.Delete() deleted the single row from the database (SQL) but removed several lines in the DataDrigView.

Comment: Correction: drToDelete.Delete only removes the data from the DataGridView, not SQL server. so I am in the same place. Can't delete a single row from the SQL database and teh DataGridView at the same time.